# Socket.io and Node.js with mysql not returning results as expeted

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

EDIT: I'm rephrasing my question: Socket.io not waiting for Callback and connection never accepted. Please see Edit 2/Attempt 1 below

This is to check authentication token against database. Can someone spot what is wrong here?

```
var checkauth = function(auth) {
    var rs = 0;
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE pword=\''+auth+'\''; 
    // Copied from debug session and got results: SELECT * FROM clients WHERE pword='d98e623c7a74a178703d17e1fd536b1488724acd41e71f178331c768c385bda2c82d2bcb60cbb4650be375ad4734c63fb694bd164c138f9abe0c51f37f9a7e33'
    var query = connection.query(sql);
    query
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log( err );
        })
        .on('result', function( row ) {
            rs = Number(row.client_id); // This never fires!!?!?!
        })
        .on('end',function(){

        });
    if (rs == 0) {
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE pword=\''+auth+'\'';
        query = connection.query(sql);
        query
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log( err );
            })
            .on('result', function( row ) {
                rs = Number(row.client_id); // This never fires!!?!?!
            })
            .on('end',function(){
            });
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Edit 1: I use the follwoing loop to authenticate socket.io connections which runs the function, ok so I understand that I have to wait for the db to finish, where would I put the callback?

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
    console.log("Query: ", socket.handshake.query);
    // return the result of next() to accept the connection.
    socket.clientid = 0;
    socket.clientid = checkauth(socket.handshake.query.auth);
    console.log("CID:"+socket.clientid);
    if (socket.clientid != 0) {
        return next();
    }
    // call next() with an Error if you need to reject the connection.
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

EDIT 2/ Attempt 1 according to Johannes' suggest:

```
var checkauth = function(auth, cb) {
    var rs = 0;
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE pword=?';
    var query = connection.query(sql, [auth]);
    query
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .on('result', function(row) {
            rs = Number(row.client_id);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            if (rs == 0) {
                sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE pword=?';
                query = connection.query(sql, [auth]);
                query
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                    .on('result', function(row) {
                        rs = Number(row.client_id);
                    })
                    .on('end', function() {
                        cb(rs);
                    });
            }
        });
}

io.use(function(socket, next){
    console.log("Query: ", socket.handshake.query);
    // return the result of next() to accept the connection.
    socket.clientid = 0;
    var auth = socket.handshake.query.auth;

    checkauth(auth, function(clientid){
        socket.clientid = clientid;
        if (clientid != 0) {
            return next();
        }
        console.log('CLIENID', clientid);
        next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    });

    // if (socket.clientid != 0) {
    //     return next();
    // }
    // // call next() with an Error if you need to reject the connection.
    // next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors logged?

Comment: nothing, no errors, the debugger just goes over the query, doesn't hit on error, on results or on end

Comment: return rs should be inside callback otherwise it will return rs == 0 all the time

Comment: This is all async so you have to wait until the db call is finished

Comment: @shikhar do you mean like: query.on('result',func(row) { rs = row.clinet_id; return rs; });  Itried but now returns undefined

Comment: @Johannes Merz ok I understand now, I'll change and post an update if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole process is async. You have to do 2 things:

Move everything into the event callback and
add a callback or promise to your checkAuth function. You also should escape your inserted data.

EDITED SOLUTION

```
var checkauth = function(auth, cb) {
    var rs = 0;
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE pword=?';
    var query = connection.query(sql, [auth], (err, client) => {
        if(err || !client || client.length < 1) return cb(err || new Error('unkown client')); 
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE pword=?';
        query = connection.query(sql, [auth], (err, user) => {
            if(err || !user || user.length < 1) return cb(err || new Error('unkown user'));
            cb(null, client[0].client_id);
        });
    });
}
```

Note: why are you doing 2 queries in the first place and storing the password for each client of the user?

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

```
var checkauth = function(auth, cb) {
    var rs = 0;
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE pword=?';
    var query = connection.query(sql, [auth]);
    query
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .on('result', function(row) {
            rs = Number(row.client_id); // This never fires!!?!?!
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            if (rs == 0) {
                sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE pword=?';
                query = connection.query(sql, [auth]);
                query
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                    .on('result', function(row) {
                        rs = Number(row.client_id); // This never fires!!?!?!
                    })
                    .on('end', function() {
                        cb(rs);
                    });
            }
        });
}

checkauth(123, function(clientId){
    console.log('CLIENID', clientId);
});
```

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for the suggestion but I believe it is something to do with the io.use not waiting for the checkauth to complete, please see my edit/atempt1

Comment: Thanks Johannes, that led me to the answer, the callback I found has to be after the first rs assignment, as well as after the second rs assignment in the result part of the query.

Comment: @johan that's impossible as the cb would be called twice this way. You could simplify this whole thing though.

Comment: oooh yes, that answer is even shorter and better! The reason why I have to check two tables is because that is how it was setup, I had to develop front end from an existing back-end.